# Get name of Bluetooth device from address

Tags: winapi, bluetooth, winsock

Given a Bluetooth device address (represented by a `SOCKADDR_BTH` struct), is there a way to get the name of the device? using `getnameinfo` returns `EAI_FAMILY` ("The sa_family member of socket address structure pointed to by the sa parameter is not supported."):

```
// {B62C4E8D-62CC-404b-BBBF-BF3E3BBB1374}
DEFINE_GUID(g_guidServiceClass, 0xb62c4e8d, 0x62cc, 0x404b, 0xbb, 0xbf, 
0xbf, 0x3e, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x13, 0x74);

SOCKADDR_BTH SockAddrBthServer;
SockAddrBthServer.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
SockAddrBthServer.serviceClassId = g_guidServiceClass;
SockAddrBthServer.port = 0;
SockAddrBthServer.btAddr = //Filled with Bluetooth device address

char hostname[NI_MAXHOST] = {0};
char servInfo[NI_MAXSERV] = {0};

int ret = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &SockAddrBthServer, 
sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH), hostname, NI_MAXHOST, servInfo, NI_MAXSERV, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [BluetoothGetDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothgetdeviceinfo) function to get remote device's name. Also you can resolve during discovering.

Please note that device name of NEW device may be empty if you try to read it right after discovering.

The best way is to subscribe for WM_DEVICECHANGE message (refer to MSDN WM_DEVICECHANGE and Bluetooth).

Comment: This requires a handle to the device. I don't have a handle - I only have an address and I want to get the name.

Comment: It does not need device handle. It needs only MAC. Have you took a look on link?